# How to hide the scroll bar markers on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

How can I disable the markers shown as thick horizontal yellow and blue lines on top of the scroll bar on Android Studio v2.2.3

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the orange "inspection lines" by click on the "man in a hat" icon in the lower right corner of the window. Then choose highlighting level "syntax".

[image: lower right corner of window]

Answer (score 0):

Look under Editor > General > Appearance

You can adjust the settings there.